# Preventing weird 'bump' with CSS borders

Tags: css

Using CSS to create triangles by using the 'border-width' parameter.

```
<div id="my-weird-triangle"></div>
<style type="text/css">
    #my-weird-triangle{
        border-color: blue black black blue;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:50px 50px 50px 50px;
        width:0;
        height:0;
    }
</style>
```

Creates an output like

[image: Weird big]

Depending on your screens, you may or may not notice, but if you zoom in to the center of the triangle there is a small (probably 1px) 'bump' which makes the triangle look odd

[image: Weird small]

How would I get a pure CSS[3] right angle triangle without this odd bump in the middle?

Comment: What browser/OS do you see this on? I just did a jsfiddle and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Firefox, OS/X. Looks the same to me in both FF and Chrome. Safari and Opera it's fine. I don't care about IE (I also don't have it)

Comment: It's probably a browser/OS-specific rendering issue that you can't do anything about other than tweak the border size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change each border color you will notice that the top and bottom triangles don't touch. You can change the width to 1px to correct it.

```
   #my-weird-triangle{
        border-color: blue black black blue;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:50px 50px 50px 50px;
        width:1px;
        height:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only two of the borders, so there won't be a *bump*:

```
#my-weird-triangle2{
    border-color: blue black black blue;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:100px 100px 0 0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
```

And here is an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/1731728